# I cannot get the email address to properly update from my user account management form

Tags: frontend, usermodel

I figure I must need to pass the current user's password along with the updated email address upon form submit. However, I cannot get the email address change to take. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's my code snippet:

```html
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="account-edit">

    {{ getCsrfInput() }}

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="{{ currentUser.password }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="account">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="deleteUserPhoto" id="deleteUserPhotoInput" value="">

    {% if currentUser.firstName %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
            <input name="firstName" value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if currentUser.lastName %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br>
            <input name="lastName" value="{{ currentUser.lastName }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if currentUser.email %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label><br>
            <input name="email" value="{{ currentUser.email }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {# Check to see if the user has a photo  #}
    {% if currentUser.photoUrl %}
        <label for="userPhoto">Edit Photo</label><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <figure>
                <div class="cover"></div>
                <img src="{{ currentUser.photoUrl (100) }}" />
                <a href="#" id="deleteUserPhotoAction" class="">Delete</a>
            </figure>
            {# If a photo exists, give the option to change the user photo #}          
            <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="Change Photo">

        </div>
    {% else %}

    {# If no photo exists, give the option to upload a new one #}
        <label for="userPhoto">Upload Photo</label><br>
        <div class="form-group">
        <figure><img src="/assets/img/user.gif" /></figure>
            <input type="file" name="userPhoto" value="Upload">
        </div>
    {% endif %}


    <input type="submit" value="Update Account" class="btn profile-save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Craft 2.3, the rules for changing an existing password are:

If you're editing your existing account OR you're an administrator OR you have the 'changeUserEmails' permission set on your user account, then you need to supply *your* existing user account's password as a hidden input (not the current password for the account you're trying to change).

```html
<input type="text" id="currentPassword" name="password" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I've tried doing this via a hidden field, but it still will not work. Is this the wrong approach?
`<input type="hidden" id="currentPassword" name="password" value="{{ currentUser.password }}">`

Comment: Sorry... forgot the logic around this changed for the 2.3 release.  Just updated my answer.

Comment: @BradBell So there's no option to bypass that requirement?

Comment: @HerbHimes That won't work Herb, the password is stored in the DB hashed for security reasons, so when you submit it as a hidden field, it is passing along the hashed version and not your actual password.

Comment: @MikePierce correct